# Deployed Node app to Google Cloud App Service-how do I edit my code?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I deployed as per the official documentation, using a yaml file, valid package.json, and the gcloud app deploy command. Now, I'd like to edit my configuration files. But when I open the cloud shell code editor, I don't see any files; all I see is a file called README-cloudshell.txt. How can I actually get to my code?

Comment: From where did you deploy your application? From your computer or from Cloud Shell?

Comment: From my computer.

Comment: Then it's normal that there are no files in Cloud Shell: Cloud Shell is independent from App Engine, it doesn't have your files there. If you want to change anything in your project, you'll have to do it from your computer (or copy your code to your Cloud Shell in some way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Shell is independent from App Engine, it doesn't have your App Engine files there.

If you want to change anything in your project, you'll have to do it from your computer (or copy your code to your Cloud Shell in some way, like uploading first to Cloud Storage and downloading back to Cloud Shell)